# Zend Error via my INI file

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am getting the following error on my site, however, i don't know what I am to do.  I know I am missing something, however, I just can't figure it out.

You can see what I am trying to achieve here: [4.6.4. Zend_Application_Resource_Session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.db)

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Exception' with message 'No adapter found for Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php:667 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(652): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupDatabaseAdapter() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTable.php(401): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setup() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(286): Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable->_setup() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\verelo\library\Zend\Session\SaveHandler\DbTable.php(205): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->__construct(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\Zend\Application\Resource\Session.php(59): Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable->__construct(Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\Zend\Application\Resource\ResourceAbstract.php(93): Zend_Application_Resource_Session->setSaveHandler(Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\Zend\Application\Resource\ResourceAbstract.php(72): Zend_Application_R in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\library\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php on line 667

Here is my config.ini file:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "app"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
;resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "actions"
;resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
;resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "site"
;resources.frontController.defaultAction = "home"
;resources.frontController.defaultModule = "static"
;resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/subdir"
;resources.frontController.plugins.foo = "My_Plugin_Foo"
;resources.frontController.plugins.bar = "My_Plugin_Bar"
resources.frontController.env = APPLICATION_ENV

resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"

resources.view[] = 
resources.view.encoding = "UTF-8"
resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/scripts"

resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
resources.session.saveHandler.class = "Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.name = "session"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary.session_id = "session_id"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary.save_path = "save_path"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary.name = "name"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primaryAssignment.sessionId = "sessionId"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primaryAssignment.sessionSavePath = "sessionSavePath"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primaryAssignment.sessionName = "sessionName"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.modifiedColumn = "modified"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.dataColumn = "session_data"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.lifetimeColumn = "lifetime"

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
```

I removed the root password of course, however, that is all I modified for this post.

Comment: It looks like the db resource isn't initialised before the session, or it's not registered as the default table adapter - I haven't yet worked out why though

Comment: I have the resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true set in my resourcem I just don't understand why I get this message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to ensure that the database resource is loaded first. The easiest way is to add a new function to application/Bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    public function _initSessionAfterDb()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('db');
        $this->bootstrap('session');
    }

}
```

Of course, you'd expect this to happen automatically, so I suspect that there's a dependency bug within Zend_Applicaton's session resource...