# how to use Zend_Loader_PluginLoader?

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to optimize zend for performance.
I used as much cache as possible and got to the code of this [page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.pluginloader.html#zend.loader.pluginloader.performance.example) 
where do i have to write it ? i tried putting it in bootstrap `__initAutoload()` but the profiler shows no change whatsover

```
$classFileIncCache = APPLICATION_PATH . '/../data/pluginLoaderCache.php';
if (file_exists($classFileIncCache)) {
    include_once $classFileIncCache;
}
Zend_Loader_PluginLoader::setIncludeFileCache($classFileIncCache);
```

Can someone explain how to use it pluginloader and if it has a performance increase?

here is part of my bootstrap

```
protected function _initSessionAfterDb()
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100562/zend-error-via-my-ini-file
        $this->bootstrap('db');
        $this->bootstrap('session');
    }

protected function _initSession()
    {

         $this->bootstrap('cache');//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271018/zend-how-to-enable-cachemetadata-on-session-table
        //NOTE: this config is also passed to Zend_Db_Table so anything specific
        //to the table can be put in the config as well
        $config = array(
            'name'              => 'session', //table name as per Zend_Db_Table
            'primary'           => array(
                'session_id',   //the sessionID given by PHP
                'save_path',    //session.save_path
                'name',         //session name
                //'cols' => array('session_id', 'save_path', 'name', 'modified', 'lifetime', 'session_data')
            ),
            'primaryAssignment' => array(
                //you must tell the save handler which columns you
                //are using as the primary key. ORDER IS IMPORTANT
                'sessionId', //first column of the primary key is of the sessionID
                'sessionSavePath', //second column of the primary key is the save path
                'sessionName', //third column of the primary key is the session name
            ),
            'modifiedColumn'    => 'modified',     //time the session should expire
            'dataColumn'        => 'session_data', //serialized data
            'lifetimeColumn'    => 'lifetime',     //end of life for a specific record
            'user_id' => 'user_id'
        );
        //Tell Zend_Session to use your Save Handler
        $savehandler = new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($config);


        //http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable
        //cookie persist for 30 min
        $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');


        $seconds = $config->session->seconds_life;

        //make the session persist for 30 min
        $savehandler->setLifetime($seconds)
            ->setOverrideLifetime(true);

        Zend_Session::setSaveHandler($savehandler);

        Zend_Session::start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not starting on the good foot, early optimization is the root of all evil. First I think you should investigate which part of your application is the slowest and try to fix it, xdebug should be able to help to get some performance data.

The plugin loader cache would increase the performance but not by a great deal, the framework search in the filesystem the plugins you are using. Enabling the cache would skip the searching process but I doubt it would make your application 50% faster all suddendly.

Also to answer where you should write it, like you mentioned the bootstrap is probably the best place.

Comment: the application is almost finished and i am usign xdebug with WinCacheGrind, wanted to optimize those 200ms of bootstrap for each request...

Comment: @max4ever: how many routes you have, also are you sure that the database access is not the problem?

Comment: not using routes, i mean only default mapping of /module/controller/action/... my bootstrap->_initSessionAfterDb is the one that costs the most, about 70-80ms

Comment: _initSessionAfterDb do what exactly?

Comment: i updated and posted the code, there is no _initDB in my bootstrap

Comment: maxever is there a specific reason why you save session in the database?

Comment: yes i needed to be able to logout users when deleting them and needed to allow google to contact my site on behalf of a user if his session is not expired

Comment: Does memcache wouldn't be better?